# linux kernel 5.8 can't work with Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: drivers, grub2, kernel

I have an R7-4800H (the graphics card is rx vega7) laptop with ubuntu 18.04.5 installed. I just installed the [5.8 kernel](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8/) on it. After the installation is complete, it cannot enter the system after rebooting, and grub outputs the following information:

```
[]pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
[]integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
[]snd_pci_acp3x 0000:03:00.5: Invalid ACP audio mode: 0
[]ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECSI] (00000000e7b8bf66) [EmbeddedControl] (202000110/evregion-127)
[]ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl(ID=3) has no handler (20200110/exfldio-261)
[]ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC.ECRD due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20200110/psparse-529)
[]ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.UBTC._DSM due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20200110/psparse-529)
[]ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: ucsi_acpi_dsm: failed to evaluate _DSM 2
```

Comment: Mainline kernels are for testing purposes. Also, what is the question you're asking exactly?

Comment: [A new question with a very similar situation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/635492/258991) was just posted on Unix&Linux.SE.  The error messages look essentially the same, with only minor variations because of different hardware. In a situation like this, I'd advise booting with verbose boot messages (edit kernel boot options to remove `quiet` if it's there, or add `verbose` if not).